# Exclude a region in 3D plot

Tags: plotting, regions

I need to exclude a region of $\pi/3\leq x \leq 2 \pi/3 $ and $\pi/3\leq y \leq 2\pi/3$
of this 3D plot:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x*y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]
```

How to do it?

Comment: I also want to evaluate the numerical values of the same function excluding the region.

Answer (score 6):

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Nor[Pi/3 <= x <= 2Pi/3, Pi/3 <= y <= 2Pi/3 ]]]
```

[image]

Also

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[{Nor[Pi/3 <= x <= 2Pi/3, Pi/3 <= y <= 2Pi/3 ]}, 
   {{x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi,  Pi}}];

Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, y} ∈ ir]
```

> same picture

```
Plot3D[Piecewise[{{Sin[x y], Nor[Pi/3 <= x <= 2 Pi/3, Pi/3 <= y <= 2 Pi/3]}}, 
  Undefined], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]
```

> same picture

```
 Plot3D[ConditionalExpression[Sin[x y], Nor[Pi/3 <= x <= 2 Pi/3, Pi/3 <= y <= 2 Pi/3]],
  {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]
```

> same picture

Comment: I need to exclude both x and y within pi/3 to 2pi/3 simultaneously. Here only x is excluded.

Comment: @PriyaMaji, please see the corrected version.

Comment: thanks a lot. What should I do if I calculate the numerical value of the same function excluding the regions?

Comment: Priya, if you define, say,  `func[x_,y_]:=ConditionalExpression[Sin[x y], Nor[Pi/3 <= x <= 2 Pi/3, Pi/3 <= y <= 2 Pi/3]]`, then, for example,  `func[Pi/10, Pi/3]` will return undefined, and `func[Pi/10, Pi/5] ` will return `Sin[\[Pi]^2/50]`. (Similarly  for `Piecewise`).

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to using [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) is to use [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html)

```
Plot3D[
 ConditionalExpression[
  Sin[x*y], (x < Pi/3 || x > 2 Pi/3) && (y < Pi/3 || y > 2 Pi/3)], {x, -Pi, 
  Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I calculate the numerical values of the same function what should I use to exclude the regions.

Comment: `f[x_, y_] := ConditionalExpression[Sin[x*y], (x < Pi/3 || x > 2 Pi/3) && (y < Pi/3 || y > 2 Pi/3)];`

Answer (score 3):

Other similar way.

```
f2[x_, y_] := 
 If[! (π/3 <= x <= (2 π)/3 || π/3 <= y <= (2 π)/3), 
  Sin[x*y], Undefined]
f3[x_, y_] := 
 Piecewise[{{Sin[
     x*y], ! (π/3 <= x <= (2 π)/3 || π/3 <= y <= (
        2 π)/3)}}, Undefined]
f4[x_, y_] := 
 Piecewise[{{None, (π/3 <= x <= (2 π)/3 || π/3 <= y <= (
       2 π)/3)}}, Sin[x*y]]
```